# How to implement dynamic subscribers with KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to implement dynamic subscribers in a kdb-tick system whereby a subset of the events are passed to a given consumer based on a query supplied by the consumer.

For instance given a batch of events i.e.:

```
flip `source`channel`value!(10?`a`b`c;10?`a`b`c;10?10)

source channel value
--------------------
a      a       4
b      b       5
a      c       4
b      a       2
c      c       7
c      b       8
c      a       5
a      c       6
b      a       4
b      a       1
```

The tickerplant should only send the events without a channel of `c i.e.

```
source channel value
--------------------
a      a       4
b      b       5 
b      a       2 
c      b       8
c      a       5 
b      a       4
b      a       1
```

I have tried to implement this by parsing a dynamic conditional as follows:

```
q).tp.subscribers

hp        | host isOpen port   h   subs
----------| --------------------------------------------------
:test:5000| test 0      5000   6   "enlist(not;(in;`channel;enlist`c))"
```

Whereby subs is a conditional argument to a functional select statement that is used in the following code:

```
.tp.send:{neg[x] y};

.tp.reval:{[batch;subscriber]
  .tp.send[raze .subscriber`h] reval[parse["?[batch;",raze[subscriber`subs],";0b;()]"]]
  };

// Called with event batch 
.tp.broadcast:{[batch]
   .tp.reval[batch]'[select from .tp.subscribers where isOpen] 
  };
```

This fails on account of batch not being addressable in a non global context through a functional select statement.
I was wondering how this functionality might be effectively achieved?

Could anyone advise me on or point me to information pertaining to a solution for this problem statement.
Your advice would very much appreciated.
Apologies if this is a newbie question.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the fact that you're expecting a string form of a conditional argument is part of your problem (that in turn requires you to `parse` a stringified functional select and that parse assumes global).

Why not expect a list form of the conditional argument instead? Then there's no need to parse and you can create a local functional select. E.g.

```
.tp.subscribers:([hp:1#`:test:5000]subs:enlist(not;(in;`channel;1#`c)))

q){[batch] reval ?[batch;(0!.tp.subscribers)`subs;0b;()]}flip `source`channel`value!(10?`a`b`c;10?`a`b`c;10?10)
source channel value
--------------------
a      a       4
b      b       5
b      a       2
c      b       8
c      a       5
b      a       4
b      a       1
```

Or have the user specify a lambda and run that (though I guess you would lose the ability to use `reval` in that case):

```
.tp.subscribers:([hp:1#`:test:5000]subs:enlist{select from x where not channel=`c})

q){[batch] @[first(0!.tp.subscribers)`subs;batch;()]}flip `source`channel`value!(10?`a`b`c;10?`a`b`c;10?10)
source channel value
--------------------
a      b       9
c      b       0
b      b       0
b      a       9
b      a       3
b      a       9
```

Comment: Hi @terrylynch, thanks for this answer. Both cases should be workable, though the first one would be better with `reval` (considering user input) as you mentioned. Is there any way that one might succinctly convert a string version of enlist(not;(in;`channel;1#`c)) i.e. "enlist(not;(in;`channel;1#`c))" to its analogous representation in q? Im having problems using `parse` on this i.e. ***?[batch;enlist(not;(in;`channel;1#`c));0b;()]*** <> ***?[batch;parse[subs];0b;()]*** where ***subs = "enlist(not;(in;`channel;1#`c))"***. Thanks

Comment: q) parse"enlist(not;(in;`channel;1#`c))" =
enlist
(enlist;~:;(enlist;in;,`channel;(#;1;,`c)))

Comment: I believe you should be able to `value` the string, aka ```value"enlist(not;(in;`channel;enlist`c))"```